# Using generate_serires with partition by generate triple duplicate row

Tags: sql, postgresql, generate-series

I have a table which look like this:

```
 dt                     type
-----------------------------
2019-07-01 10:00:00       A
2019-07-01 10:15:00       A
2019-07-01 11:00:00       A
2019-07-01 08:30:00       B
2019-07-01 08:45:00       B
2019-07-01 09:30:00       B
```

Each type has it own dt value but each type should have a consecutive 15 minute range dt. But some row are missing. So, I used `generate_strings()` to add  date and `partition by` to do it based on each type column by using this:

```
SELECT 
generate_series(min(dt) over (partition by type),
                max(dt) over (partition by type), interval '15 minute')
, type
FROM t
```

which I generate datetime in dt column based on in min to max dt with a range of 15 minutes.

This is what I expect to get:

```
dt                     type
-----------------------------
2019-07-01 10:00:00       A
2019-07-01 10:15:00       A
2019-07-01 10:30:00       A
2019-07-01 10:45:00       A
2019-07-01 11:00:00       A
2019-07-01 08:30:00       B
2019-07-01 08:45:00       B
2019-07-01 09:00:00       B
2019-07-01 09:15:00       B
2019-07-01 09:30:00       B
```

But what I got as a result is like the expected one but it return triple for each type and datetime.

E.g.

```
dt                     type
-----------------------------
2019-07-01 10:00:00       A
2019-07-01 10:15:00       A
2019-07-01 10:30:00       A
2019-07-01 10:45:00       A
2019-07-01 11:00:00       A
2019-07-01 10:00:00       A
2019-07-01 10:15:00       A
2019-07-01 10:30:00       A
2019-07-01 10:45:00       A
2019-07-01 11:00:00       A
2019-07-01 10:00:00       A
2019-07-01 10:15:00       A
2019-07-01 10:30:00       A
2019-07-01 10:45:00       A
2019-07-01 11:00:00       A
2019-07-01 08:30:00       B
. . .
```

This also happened to type B as well.

So, from my query, what do I need to change to get the expected result?

Comment: set returning functions should be used in the `from` clause, not in the `select` list to avoid strange corner cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just want to run `generate_series()` over the aggregation:

```
SELECT type, generate_series(min_dt, max_dt, interval '15 minute')
FROM (SELECT type, MIN(dt) as min_dt, MAX(dt) as max_dt
      FROM t
      GROUP BY type
     ) t;
```

The window functions start by adding the min and max value to each row.  Then each row gets its own series.

Comment: I edited the `MAX(dt) as min_dt` to `MIN(dt) as min_dt` also add  `, type` in subquery

Comment: I adapt this query to the query from your answer in my previous question. And the calculation gone wrong. Check the last query out from [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=1ed9a6a9feb1043a022d5e56661fb808)

Comment: Thank you. This is my final one without error [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=7de09ea309a1de3132874f01c21e2bdd)